# Collecting algorithm captions in WinEdt

Tags: algorithms, winedt

I've installed the add-on [Figures&Tables](http://www.winedt.org/Config/Tree/Figures.php) in WinEdt, which lets me collect table and figure captions in WinEdt's Tree.

I would like to be able to collect algorithm captions, as well.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Table test}
  \end{table}

  \begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Figure test}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{algorithm}[h]
    \caption{Algorithm test}
  \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

WinEdt's Tree shows

[image]

Is there any way to show a branch for algorithms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update (2016-04-10)

By installing the add-on [Floats](http://www.winedt.org/config/tree/Floats.html) you will be able to collect algorithm captions.

---

### Original answer

Yes, it is possible. Follow these steps:

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. In the "Options Interface", double-click the "Tree" item (`Tree.ini` gets opened)
3. Since you have the add-on "Figures&Tables" installed, you should have a line

   ```
   END="Tables-TeX"
   ```

   Just after that, insert the following lines

   ```
   BRANCH="Algorithms-TeX"
     BRANCH_CAPTION="Algorithms  (#)"
     // Change Mode from TeX to ? to disable this item
     BRANCH_MODE_FILTER="TeX|DTX;INS;STY;AUX"
     BRANCH_ICON="CodeSample"
     BRANCH_SORTED=0
     BRANCH_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
     BRANCH_IGNORE_COMMENTS=1
     BRANCH_IGNORE_VERBATIM=1
     BRANCH_EXPANDED=0
     ITEM="\begin{algorithm}?\end{algorithm}"
       ALT="\begin{algorithm*}?\end{algorithm*}"
       ALT="\begin{procedure}?\end{procedure}"
       ALT="\begin{procedure*}?\end{procedure*}"
       ALT="\begin{function}?\end{function}"
       ALT="\begin{function*}?\end{function*}"
       ALT="\begin{algorithm2e}?\end{algorithm2e}"
       ALT="\begin{algorithm2e*}?\end{algorithm2e*}"
       MODE_FILTER="TeX"
       CASE_SENSITIVE=1
       BEGINNING_OF_LINE_ONLY=1
       CURRENT_DOCUMENT_ONLY=1
       ALL_OPENED_DOCUMENTS=0
       COMPLETE_PROJECT_TREE=1
       ICON="FlagPurple"
       LEVEL=0
       CAPTION="%[!|Exe('%b\Macros\Gather\FigTab.edt');|];%-0"
       MAX_LINE_SPAN=99
       ON_CLICK_MACRO="TreeTrack(2,1);"
       ON_DBL_CLICK_MACRO="TreeTrack(2,2);"
       ACTION="Find"
         IMAGE="Find"
         MACRO="TreeTrack(2);"
       SUBSTITUTION="\label{*}"
         SUB_FIND="\\label\{*\}"
         SUB_REPLACE=""
         SUB_REG_EX=1
         SUB_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
       SUBSTITUTION="  "
         SUB_FIND=" +{ }"
         SUB_REPLACE=" "
         SUB_REG_EX=1
         SUB_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
       SUBSTITUTION="\dots"
         SUB_FIND="\dots"
         SUB_REPLACE="..."
         SUB_REG_EX=0
         SUB_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
       SUBSTITUTION="\ldots"
         SUB_FIND="\ldots"
         SUB_REPLACE="..."
         SUB_REG_EX=0
         SUB_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
     END="\begin{algorithm}?\end{algorithm}"
   END="Algorithms-TeX"
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.

---

Now you will be able to collect algorithm captions for the following environments, defined by the `algorithm` and the `algorithm2e` packages:

- `algorithm`
- `algorithm*`
- `procedure`
- `procedure*`
- `function`
- `function*`
- `algorithm2e`
- `algorithm2e*`

With your MWE you will get this result:

[image]

Comment: @Sterry You're welcome. Since it seems to be a good addition, I'm thinking to add it in the add-on Figures&Tables. When it will be available, I will inform you so that you can undo these changes and install the updated package :-)

Comment: @Sterry A new package called "Floats" is available at http://www.winedt.org/Config/Tree/Floats.php. It contains these improvements and much more. Please undo these changes and uninstall "Figures&Tables" before installing the new add-on.

Comment: Wonderful! Great add-on.